# Connect Multiple Microsoft Visual Studio to same projects

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

Me and my couple of friends will start working on a C# database project. We will use Microsoft VS 2015 and SQL Server 2014. Is there any way that our Visual Studio (installed on separate laptop) can connect to the same project?

For example, if one of my friends removes a class from the project, that class should also be removed from our project. Also, if he adds something, that change should also be shown on our VS solution.

Comment: try git,  do a bunch of reading on source control and what git is first.  also have a look at http://ohshitgit.com/   and perhaps use something like smartgit.   Visual Studio also supports git.   There are other advantages to using source control,  like being able to see what changes you have made to to your code over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Team Foundation**

> You can use Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC) to scale from small
>   to large projects, and by using server workspaces, you can scale up to
>   very large codebases with millions of files per branch and large
>   binary files. TFVC is a centralized version control system that lets
>   you apply granular permissions and restrict access down to a file
>   level. Because your team checks in all their work into your Team
>   Foundation server, you can easily audit changes and identify which
>   user checked in a changeset. By using compare and annotate you can
>   identify the exact changes that they made.

https://www.visualstudio.com/tfs/

**GitLab**

> GitLab Inc. is a company based on the GitLab open-source project.
>   GitLab is an application to code, test, and deploy code together. It
>   provides Git repository management with fine grained access controls,
>   code reviews, issue tracking, activity feeds, wikis, and continuous
>   integration.

https://about.gitlab.com/

**Bitbucket**

> Bitbucket is a web-based hosting service for projects that use either
>   the Mercurial (since launch) or Git (since October 2011) revision
>   control systems. Bitbucket offers both commercial plans and free
>   accounts. It offers free accounts with an unlimited number of private
>   repositories (which can have up to five users in the case of free
>   accounts) as of September 2010, but by inviting three users to join
>   Bitbucket, three more users can be added, for eight users in total.
>   Bitbucket is written in Python using the Django web framework.

https://www.atlassian.com/software/bitbucket

Answer (score 1):

If you have db project in Visual studio you should connect it to some version control. After that every change done by your friends will be fetch/pull on your local machine and you will execute the db project. Same is for code changes in your main project. Read about svn and git and choose what is better for you.

> Git is a free and open source distributed version control system
>   designed to handle everything from small to very large projects with
>   speed and efficiency.

[Getting your project on GitHub](https://guides.github.com/introduction/getting-your-project-on-github/)

> Subversion is a free/open source version control system (VCS). That
>   is, Subversion manages files and directories, and the changes made to
>   them, over time. This allows you to recover older versions of your
>   data or examine the history of how your data changed. In this regard,
>   many people think of a version control system as a sort of “time
>   machine.”
>
> Subversion can operate across networks, which allows it to be used by
>   people on different computers. At some level, the ability for various
>   people to modify and manage the same set of data from their respective
>   locations fosters collaboration. Progress can occur more quickly
>   without a single conduit through which all modifications must occur.
>   And because the work is versioned, you need not fear that quality is
>   the trade-off for losing that conduit—if some incorrect change is made
>   to the data, just undo that change.
>
> Some version control systems are also software configuration
>   management (SCM) systems. These systems are specifically tailored to
>   manage trees of source code and have many features that are specific
>   to software development—such as natively understanding programming
>   languages, or supplying tools for building software. Subversion,
>   however, is not one of these systems. It is a general system that can
>   be used to manage any collection of files. For you, those files might
>   be source code—for others, anything from grocery shopping lists to
>   digital video mixdowns and beyond.

[Importing Data Into A Repository SVN](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-import.html)

If you are not aware with git/svn I advise you to use SVN it is easy to understand. Git has his advantages when your team is really big and for open source. Currently on this moment git is the "future" in version controls.